# Remove hash (array) from param and put in variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, variables, hash

I'm retrieving a param in a controller from a form, from which I want to remove a hash and put into a variable for later use.

Let's assume the param include the following:

```
@form_data = params[:project] // <-- :id, :title, :description, :members
```

':members' is an array (retrieved from checkboxes) and I want that array to be put in a new variable for later use, and it should be removed from the param.

```
@members // <-- should contain :members 

@project = Project.new(params[:project])  // <-- ':members' is removed
```

How could this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [delete](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-delete) method

```
@members = params[:project].delete(:members)
@project = Project.new(params[:project])
```

Answer (score 5):

You have at least two options for this.

1) Ignore the members key when you initialize the Project

```
@members = params[:project][:members]
@project = Project.new(params[:project].except(:members))
```

2) Delete the members key from the params object

```
@members = params[:project].delete(:members)
@project = Project.new(params[:project])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like :

```
 before_filter :edit_params_hash, :only => [:create]


 def edit_params_hash
      @members = params[:projects][:members] if params[:projects][:members].present?
      params[:projects][:members] ||= nil
 end
```

and then in create use

```
def create
     @project = Project.new(params[:project])
     @project.save
     @project.members = @members
end
```

:)